# Probability that the coefficients of a quadratic equation with real roots form a triangle

Tags: probability, integration, geometry, algebra-precalculus, geometric-probability

**Question**: What is the probability that the coefficients of a quadratic equation form the sides of triangle given that it has real roots? Assume that the coefficients are uniformly distributed and positive.

Note that it is sufficient to assume that the coefficients are uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$ since we can always divide by the largest coefficient to scale all the coefficients to $(0,1)$.

**Experimental data**: A simulation with $10^{10}$ trails gives the probability as $0.182185$. This could be a coincidence but this value which agrees with $\displaystyle \frac{\log \pi}{2\pi}$ to five decimal places.

**Julia code**:

```
using Random

step = target = 10^7
count = count_q = qt = 0

while 1 > 0
    count += 1
    random_numbers = rand(3)
    a = random_numbers[1]
    b = random_numbers[2]
    c = random_numbers[3]
    
    if b^2 >= 4*a*c
        count_q += 1
        if (a + b >= c) && (b + c >= a) && (c + a >= b)
            qt += 1
        end
    end
    
    if count_q >= target
        println(count," ",count_q/step," ",qt," ",qt/count_q)
        target += step
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you mean "given three uniformly distributed values, what is the probability that they form the sides of a triangle and at the same time that the corresponding quadratic has real roots"? Or "given a quadratic equation with real roots, what is the probability that the coefficients form the sides of a triangle, if the coefficients are uniformly distributed within the region of feasibility for the quadratic to have real roots"? Or something slightly different?

Comment: @RaadShaikh The second one: "given a quadratic equation with real roots, what is the probability that the coefficients form the sides of a triangle ... "

Comment: Try to conditional probability then. Spoiler we will need triple integers

Comment: I replaced the tag [tag:probability-theory] (which is “for questions solely about the modern theoretical footing for probability” by [tag:geometric-probability]. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries in choosing tags.

Comment: If I didn't mess up with the integrals, the probability of having real roots comes out to $\frac{5}{36}+\frac16\ln(2)$.

Comment: I just plugged a bunch of integrals into WA, and I think the actual probability is $\frac{-\frac{31}{12}+\frac{16}{9}\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{6}\ln\left(2\right)}{\frac{5}{36}+\frac{1}{6}\ln\left(2\right)}=\frac{-93+64\sqrt{2}+6\ln\left(2\right)}{5+6\ln\left(2\right)}\approx 0.182178$ which is pretty close to what you got from your simulation.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Plausible since yours is based on theory as opposed to just simulation. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Wlog we can take coefficients as sum and products of roots from  $y=C (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: This isn't very elegant and just brute-forces through the solution.

---

You're trying to find $$P(a+b\ge c,a+c\ge b,b+c\ge a|a,b,c\sim U(0,1),b^2-4ac\ge0)$$ which is equal to $$\frac{P(a+b\ge c,a+c\ge b,b+c\ge a,b^2-4ac\ge0|a,b,c\sim U(0,1))}{P(b^2-4ac\ge0 | a,b,c\sim U(0,1))}$$

Since $a,b,c$ are chosen uniformly, we can directly set up an integral for the denominator as $$\iiint_{R}[b^2-4ac\ge0]dA$$ where $[b^2-4ac\ge0]$, using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), is $1$ if the condition is satisfied and $0$ otherwise, and $R=[0,1]^3$. Simplifying and setting up the bounds a bit more clearly, this is equal to $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_{\min(\sqrt{4ac},1)}^11dbdcda=\int_0^1\int_0^1(1-\min(\sqrt{4ac},1))dcda$$ With the substitution $(p,r)\mapsto (p/r,r)=(a,c)$. This is equal to $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{p}^{1}\frac{1}{r}\left(1-\min\left(\sqrt{4p},1\right)\right)drdp = \int_{0}^{1}-\left(1-\min\left(\sqrt{4p},1\right)\right)\ln\left(p\right)dp$$ which simplifies to $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}-\left(1-\sqrt{4p}\right)\ln\left(p\right)dp$$ If you do go through the trouble of integrating this, or just plug it into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+1%2F4+of+-%281-sqrt%284p%29%29*ln%28p%29+dp), you get that the denominator is $$\frac{1}{36}(5+\ln(64))$$

---

Similarly, the numerator is given by $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1[a+b\ge c,a+c\ge b,b+c\ge a,b^2-4ac\ge0]dadcdb$$

The integrand is symmetric about $c=a$, so we can just consider $a\le c$ and multiply by 2. $$2\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^c[a+b\ge c,a+c\ge b,b^2-4ac\ge0]dadcdb$$ where we know $b+c\ge a$ since $c\ge a$. With the substitution $(s,m)\mapsto ((s+m)/2,(s-m)/2) = (a,c)$, we get $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{b}\int_{b}^{\min(2-m,\sqrt{b^{2}+m^{2}})}1dsdmdb=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{b}(\min(2-m,\sqrt{b^{2}+m^{2}})-b)dmdb$$ which is equal to $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\min\left(b,1-\frac{b^{2}}{4}\right)}^{b}\left(2-m-b\right)dmdb+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min\left(b,1-\frac{b^{2}}{4}\right)}\left(\sqrt{b^{2}+m^{2}}-b\right)dmdb$$[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+integral+from+0+to+b+of+%28min%282-m%2Csqrt%28b%5E2%2Bm%5E2%29%29-b%29+dm+db) spits out as $$\frac{1}{36}(-93+64\sqrt{2}+\ln(64))$$ or we can continue splitting up the integrals to get $$\int_{0}^{-2+2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{b}\left(\sqrt{b^{2}+m^{2}}-b\right)dmdb+\int_{-2+2\sqrt{2}}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-\frac{b^{2}}{4}}\left(\sqrt{b^{2}+m^{2}}-b\right)dmdb+\int_{-2+2\sqrt{2}}^{1}\int_{1-\frac{b^{2}}{4}}^{b}\left(2-m-b\right)dmdb$$ and continue on integrating.

---

If we then looked at the conditional probabilities, we get $$\frac{\frac{1}{36}(-93+64\sqrt{2}+\ln(64))}{\frac{1}{36}(5+\ln(64))}=\frac{-93+64\sqrt{2}+\ln(64)}{5+\ln(64)}\approx 0.182178$$ which is pretty close to what your simulation got.

Comment: 1) "brute-force" maybe, but very well detailed ! 2) I have found that my solution was dealing with another description of the probability space for triangles (Bertrand's paradox).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, here is a barycentric graphical representation giving a global view over the issue :

[image]

As any polynomial equation has the same roots if we multiply its coefficients by a same constant, we can assume without loss of generality that :

$$a+b+c=1\tag{1}$$

To a triangle with sides (proportional to) $a,b,c$, let us associate the point with **barycentrical coordinates** $(a,b,c)$.

1. First fact : due to triangular inequalities :

$$\begin{cases}a+b \ge c\\b+c \ge a\\c+a \ge b\end{cases},\tag{2}$$

a point representing a triangle must be inside midtriangle $A_1B_1C_1$.

2. Second fact : Discriminant condition

$$b^2 \ge 4ac\tag{3}$$

is equivalent to have this point "above" a parabola passing through points $A,C$ and having its apex in $M$, the midpoint of line segment $A_1C_1$ (represented by the area with yellow or red dots).

Therefore, the *conditional* probability we are looking for is the ratio of two areas : the area with red dots over the area with yellow dots (of course, the area with red dots is a subset of the area with yellow dots).

This ratio, obtained by a little tedious computation is equal to

$$\tfrac{1}{4}(23-16 \sqrt{2}) \approx 0.09314575... \tag{4}$$

way from the value

$$\approx 0.1821..\tag{5}$$ I was obtaining (as you),

For a long while, I have been puzzled by this huge discrepancy between the simulation results (5) and the formal calculation (4).

Then I realized that they we were faced here to a case of the so-called "Bertrand's paradox" ; with the same condition (1), there are two ways to realize it (see Matlab program below)

- (First method, as applied above) which in fact corresponds to the "broken stick" way to obtain lengths $a,b,c$. Explanation : take a stick with unit length ; break it into three parts with resp. lengths $a,b,c$. This is connected to barycentric representation.
- (Second method) by taking $a,b,c$ uniformly on $(0,1)$, then by dividing all of them by their sum $s=a+b+c$.

Matlab program with the two simulation methods :

Please note that the first, resp. second, method gives (4), resp. (5).

```
 n=100000;y=0;r=0;
 for k=1:n
    % First simulation method, corresponding to the figure
    % (aka "broken stick method) giving probability 0.093245...
    b1=rand;b2=rand;
    if b1>b2
        temp=b2;b1=b2;b2=temp; % exchange
    end;
    a=b1;b=b2-b1;c=1-b2;
    % Second simulation method (corresponding to yours)
    % with probability 0.182...
    % a=rand;b=rand;c=rand;s=a+b+c;a=a/s;b=b/s;c=c/s;
    if b^2>4*a*c
        y=y+1; % increment yellow
        if (a+b>c) && (a+c>b) && (b+c>a)
           r=r+1; % increment red
        end;
    end
 end;
 pro=r/y
```

Comment: The idea to consider a triangle known by its sidelengths through barycentric coordinates (and the fact that the corresponding points are situated in the midtriangle) can be found elsewhere, in particular in the context of geometric probability, for example [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/geoprobability.shtml)

Comment: I really like the diagrammatic representation. Makes it more intuitive.

Comment: Bertrand paradox is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) and in [this blog](https://hpaulkeeler.com/the-bertrand-paradox/) possesing numerous references

Comment: A very interesting text for a somewhat similar question [here](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath299/kmath299.htm)